# Oracle: Create schema with table of xml type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, xmltype

in the Oracle database I wanted to create a schema with a table of XMLTYPE.

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION xmlAdmin
    CREATE TABLE PossibleAnswers OF XMLTYPE;
```

In return, I get an error of **ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis**.

Is there any reason why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create the schema with a table with a column of type `XMLTYPE` rather than trying to create an object-derived table from `XMLTYPE`:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION xmlAdmin
  CREATE TABLE PossibleAnswers (value XMLTYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you tried; it won't work:

```
SQL> create schema authorization scott
  2    create table a of xmltype;
  create table a of xmltype
                 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

Though, you can create such a table itself:

```
SQL>   create table a of xmltype;

Table created.
```

If you want to create a schema **and** a table, modify `create table` statement to e.g.

```
SQL> create schema authorization scott
  2    create table b (col xmltype);

Schema created.

SQL>
```